# change bootstrap datepicker format to Server's Date format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to set Datepicker format to server's shortdate format. I am developing the portal in Asp.Net MVC 5 and using Bootstrap datepicker.

I pick the Server Date Format using

```
@CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Here is the script in my _Layout.cs file

```
@using System.Globalization;
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    format: '@CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern'
});
</script>
```

Currently the Server's Date Format is set to dd-MM-yyyy and date value is 22-09-2014 but the datepicker now shows 22-September-2014.

Upon Exploring the datepicker.js, MM translates to {January, Feburary, ..} while Windows MM translates to {01, 02, ..}.

I want the datepicker to translate MM to {01, 02, ..}, MMM to {Jan, Feb, ..}, MMMM to {January, Feburary, ..}, in-short to reflect the windows date formats.

I can't find a way to fix it, your help is much appreciated. Please note that I don't want to hard code the date format.

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format) for bootstrap datepicker listed all possible format values. So it is by design. You could modify datepicker.js to suit your needs or do some client-side convertation of server returned values.